# Warning ftp_put() filename cannot be empty

Tags: php, file-upload

I need to upload some video and audio files using php and ftp. I'm using the php built-in ftp functions but I'm having some problems with the `ftp_put()` function. While I'm testing the code, it will continue to give me an error related to the file name. How I can fix this.

Here is the output of the php console when I try to upload the file:

`Warning: ftp_put(): Filename cannot be empty in /Users/uc/Desktop/c/FtpManager.php on line 37`

And this is the `$_FILES` array dump:
`array(5) { ["name"]=> string(8) "em_1.mp4" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(1) ["size"]=> int(0) }`

The code I'm using to prototype the script is the following:

```php
<?php 
  /* Upload video */
  public function uploadVideo(array $inputFile){
      if( ftp_chdir( $this->conn, "/cloud.mywebsite.com/" ) ){
        $upload = ftp_put( $this->conn, $inputFile['video_file']['name'], $inputFile['video_file']['name'], FTP_BINARY);
        if( $upload ){
          echo 'File uploaded!';
        }
      }
  }

if(isset($_POST['upload_video'])){
  echo $ftp->uploadVideo($_FILES['video_file']);
}

?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">
  <input type="file" name="video_file" />
  <input type="submit" name="upload_video">
</form>
```

Comment: `["error"]=> int(1)` -- that means there was an error with your upload. The value 1 is a `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE` error, which [means](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini."

Comment: @rickdenhaan I'm using the embed php server of macOS. I didn't set the php ini, but the video that I'm using to test is only 3MB large. The mai problem I have is with the `ftp_put()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common reason for the error is exceeding the `maximum allowed filesize`. At the very least, check the error in the `$_FILES` entry for your file before attempting the FTP upload

```
if ($_FILES['video_file']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
  // handle the error instead of uploading e.g. give a message to user
}
```

Comment: @dwpu please share the output of print_r($_FILES)

Comment: Check the question, I've already posted it. The array has only the file name info and the error.

Comment: @dwpu as I can see the index error has value 1 which means you have error uploading the file. please check post_max_size in your ini

Comment: I've switched from the embed php server of macOS to MAMP and the files array is now filled with all the information about the video I'm using for the code test. The problem is about the `ftp_put()` only now.  Here is the `$_FILES` array content: `array(5) { ["name"]=> string(8) "em_1.mp4" ["type"]=> string(9) "video/mp4" ["tmp_name"]=> string(36) "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/php8tx1cg" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(3625754) }`

Comment: The strange issue is about a file variable that isn't present inside the code, but the consolle log me these two errors: 
`PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: file` and `PHP Warning:  ftp_put(): Filename cannot be empty `

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help and after a bit of debug of the code I've found a solution. Here is a working snippet of the code. I wasn't able to use the `ftp_put()` function because the embedded macOS php server on my machine isn't configured. I've switched from it to MAMP and I've solved the upload file size issue. I also needed to set the `ftp_pasv()` mode to on to avoid problem with the uploaded files.

```php
<?php 

class ftp{

public function ftpLogin(){
    if( ftp_login($this->conn, $this->user, $this->pwd) ){
      ftp_pasv($this->conn, true);
      echo "Connected to: $this->host !";
    }
}

public function uploadVideo(array $inputFile){
      if( ftp_chdir( $this->conn, "/mysite.subdomain.com/" ) ){
        $upload = ftp_put( $this->conn, $inputFile['name'], $inputFile['tmp_name'], FTP_BINARY);
        if( $upload ){
          echo 'File uploaded!';
        }
      }
}

}

?>
```